# Dynamically Changing the Return Type of a Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a Function that has a return-type which will dynamically change depending on the column which we are passing.
Here in the following code I am passing the column-value, column-datatype. But I am getting error while running the code.

> "A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this
>   context."

If this is not possible then how to change the return type dynamically.
Kindly suggest solution.

```
Create Function myFunction(@ColValue varchar(100), @ColReturnType varchar(100))
RETURNS @ColReturnType
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@ColValue = 'xxxxx')
    BEGIN
        return 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       return @ColValue
    END
END
```

Comment: No you can't change the return type dynamically. You could try to use [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) as a return type instead.

Comment: You can always have `NULL` as a sort of universal default result, if that's what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `xml` type instead, that would solve the problem to return arbitrary data that conforms to different contracts.