# scalar function returning sql_variant or converted data type?

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-variant

Giving the following function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[InlineMax](@val1 sql_variant, @val2 sql_variant)
RETURNS sql_variant
AS
BEGIN
    return CASE WHEN @val1 > @val2 THEN @val1 ELSE @val2 END
END
```

Is it possible to return the same datatype received on @val1 and @val2?

For example: dbo.inlineMax(1,2) returns int, while dbo.inlineMax(GETDATE(),GETDATE()+1) returns datetime?

```
RETURNS SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( @val1, 'BaseType')
```

Comment: Not really. This would return a sql_variant in all cases. Why do you need a sql_variant? In my 20+ years I have never needed anything like this. And be careful, scalar functions like this are horribly inefficient and can cause significant performance problems.

Comment: What are you saying is inneficient, the scalar function or the sql_variant? I'm using this function to build cleaner queries, and would be better to have the same function for int and datetime

Comment: Both actually. Scalar functions are very poor performers. And building a single piece of sql to handle everything is the same thing as creating a single method in a programming language that can do everything. Would you create a method in a class that can calculate tax, send an email or connect to a database based on the parameters? That is what you are trying to do here in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Changing the Return Type of a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696806/dynamically-changing-the-return-type-of-a-function)

Comment: Actually is quite different than mixing tax calculation, mailing, etc.
I'm wondering if the same logical max comparison can be done with int and datetime variables on the same scalar function, but I got it, not possible.